# IE is getting logged out / refresh on click of mailto: in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer

I am trying something very simple and I am using Angular 4 Application.

I have an href in HTML code and one link to `mailto:` email address.

When I click on link in IE11, it gets logged out automatically or page gets refreshed. When page gets refreshed, the user is back to login page.

HTML CODE

```
<a href="mailto:"myemail@gmail.com">Email me</a>
```

Any idea if anyone has faced such issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that like this:

```
<span (click)="mailMe()">Email me</span>

mailMe(){
    window.location.href = "mailto:abc@abc.com";
}
```